# Test Retrieval from Data Structure without testing Store

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Let's say I want to write some JUnit tests for a new, untested data structure BlackBox. It has an interface similar to a Map, but there's no way to tell what is going on inside of it:

```
blackBox.get(key);
blackBox.put(key, value);
```

How do I correctly unit test `.get` and `.put` in the two following scenarios? I cannot figure out how to test the two independently.

1. I am using TDD, and therefore want to write the tests first.
2. BlackBox has been written by someone else and I want to test it.

I know that if I had access to the source, I can do the following:

```
Whitebox.setInternalState(blackBox, "storage", storageObject);
assertEquals(blackBox.get("key"), expectedAnswer");
```

I can do the opposite to test `.put()`. The issue is that those tests rely on the implementation of the class.

So how can I individually test `.get` and `.put` without knowing or relying on the implementation details of the class?

Comment: .get and .put are the public interface to the class.  They don't really tell you how the class is implemented, just how you can interface with it.

Comment: Sure. So how do I test .get without testing .put, and vice verca, if I don't know the implementation & can't leverage Whitebox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cannot figure out how to test the two independently.

why do you want to do that? does the contract state they are independent? i don't think so. i'm guessing the contract says:

1. new object is created as empty so `get` will return null / throw exception.
2. when you `put` something, you can `get` it.
3. you can not `get` what you didn't `put`.
4. when you `put` many times on same key you will `get` the latest value.

and so on. you can test each of those invariants. when you use `Whitebox` you start to test implementation details, not the contract and that makes the refactoring (e.g. using faster implementation) much harder

Comment: Very helpful answer. If the root cause is "you shouldn't be testing that," it's much better to fix that than "I can't test it." I'll leave the question open for a bit to see if anyone else has a better suggestions. Otherwise I'll accept your answer.